# access denied 403 forbidden error in publishing site sharepoint item adding

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Two days ago, everything was working fine. Now when I try to add an item from my web part it is giving a 403 forbidden access denied error.

Also, I am using run with elevated privileges to insert records. It was working. Now I can manually add items, but from my web part it is not working. Also, I am not able to edit publishing pages.

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
  SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
  {
        using (SPSite ElevatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
        {
              using (SPWeb ElevatedWeb = ElevatedSite.OpenWeb(web.ID))
              {
                    // Code Using the SPWeb Object Goes Here
              }
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your password has expired by connecting to your sharepoint site with a browser. I have had this issue twice already, twice it was a expired password problem.

*(note: I will remove this answer if not relevant)*

Comment: which password, site collection administrator i am able to open sites and able to insert data manually.